# yuv10 bits texture in Metal

Tags: metal, gpu, core-video

I'm trying to convert my openGL shaders into metal shaders for converting yuv10 bits texture to rgba texture.

With openGL I was using this GLSL code [from this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20317882/how-can-i-correctly-unpack-a-v210-video-frame-using-glsl)

I did the conversion, but the result is not the one I expected.

I think it is because I use

```
 tex2d.sample(sampler2d, x, y).rgba;
```

instead of

```
texelFetch(tex, ivec2(sourceColumnIndexY, texcoordDenorm.y)
```

Is there any equivalent to texelFetch in Metal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really explain in what way "the result is not the one I expected". You also didn't explain things like what Metal pixel format you're using for the input texture.

Anyway, the Metal function that corresponds to `texelFetch()` is simply the `read()` member function of the texture types. For example, `texture2d<T>` has these two member functions:

```
Tv read(uint2 coord, uint lod = 0) const
Tv read(ushort2 coord, ushort lod = 0) const
```

where `Tv` is the 4-component vector whose component type is `T`.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for. And now it works.